# Is there a function akin to fprintf but only returns the result of formated string in C?

Tags: c, string

```
fprintf(stderr,"Error in pcap_findalldevs: %s\n", errbuf);
```

I don't want to output anything via `fprintf`,but only the result of `"Error in pcap_findalldevs: %s\n", errbuf`,what's the function for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int sprintf(char * ptr, const char * format, ...)
```

Writes the output and a terminating null to a buffer at ptr, returns the number of characters written excluding the null. Dangerous if you don't know how big your output should be, it will blindly write past the end of the buffer.

```
int snprintf(char * ptr, size_t n, const char * format, ...)
```

Same as `sprintf`, but will write a maximum of `n` characters, including the trailing null. Returns the number of characters that would be written if `n` was large enough, so that you can reallocate your buffer if necessary.

```
int asprintf(char ** ptr, const char * format, ...)
```

Same as `sprintf` except a double pointer is passed in, the buffer will be resized if necessary to fit the output. This is a GNU extension, also available in BSD, it can be emulated like (Ignoring error checking)

```
int asprintf(char ** ptr, const char * format, ...){
    va_list vlist;
    va_start(vlist,format);
    int n = vsnprintf(NULL,0,format,vlist);
    *ptr = realloc(*ptr,n+1);
    n = vsnprintf(*ptr,n+1,format,vlist);
    va_end(vlist);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to restrict the length of the result string,how do I make it work for arbitary long string?

Comment: The `asprintf` function will resize the buffer to the required length itself, otherwise use `snprintf` to check the necessary buffer size.

Answer (score 4):

`snprintf` allows you to format to a char buffer and performs bounds checking to ensure the buffer is not overrun.

The commonly used `sprintf` does not perform bounds checking, and as such is inherently unsafe.

Comment: But I need to allocate enough space for `char * string` before calling it,how do I know how much space is required?

Comment: @httpinterpret: With your example, the space required is `strlen("Error in pcap_findalldevs: \n") + strlen(errbuf) + 1` (it's not always so easy to calculate, though).

Answer (score 1):

That is [`sprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) which also has some useful variations, like `vsprintf()` which takes a pointer to an argument list.  There are also buffer protection versions in some implementations.

Answer (score 1):

`sprintf` copies the result to a `char *` instead of writing it to `stdout` or a file.

**Syntax differences**

`printf(const char format, ...)`

`fprintf(FILE * file, const char format, ...)`

`sprintf(char * string, const char format, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf` is the original call, but should be considered deprecated in favor of `snprintf` which allows you to pass a size.  Another alternative is `asprintf`, which will allocate a string large enough to hold the result.